# OnPress function doesn't print any in console

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-test, flutter-onpressed

I have given a print("object") In Floating Action Button In default code of Flutter counter App
When I hit enter it doesn't print anything in console,It works on Web,Its working on Infinix Zero X Neo but on my mobile Tecno Camon 18p its not working
I have tried all possible solutions like flutter clean and so on
I have checked StackoverFlow but didn't find any thing
It was working fine but From last night this is happening

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet that will reproduce the error

Comment: Can you change some text and `run` again, maybe you run it on wrong device.

Comment: I will add code snippet ASAP,I have tried on web,Infinix mobile its working perfectly but on my Tecno camon 18p, it doesn't print any thing in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just uninstalled flutter, and installed SDK again,Now its working properly
Thanks all friends who tried to help